# Are there any file systems that do not use file paths?

Tags: file, filesystems, checksum

File paths are inherently dubious when working with data.
Lets say I have a hypothetical situation with a program called `find_brca`, and some data called `my.genome` and both are in the `/Users/Desktop/` directory.

`find_brca` takes a single argument, a genome, runs for about 4 hours, and returns the probability of that individual developing breast cancer in their lifetime. Some people, presented with a very high % probability, might then immediately have both of their breasts removed as a precaution.

Obviously, in this scenario, it is absolutely vital that `/Users/Desktop/my.genome` actually contains the genome we think it does. There are no do-overs. "oops we used an old version of the file from a previous backup" or any other technical issue will not be acceptable to the patient. How do we ensure we are analysing the file we think we are analysing?

To make matters trickier, lets also assert that we cannot modify `find_brca` itself, because we didn't write it, its closed source, proprietary, whatever.

You might think MD5 or other cryptographic checksums might be able to come to the rescue, and while they do help to a degree, you can only MD5 the file before and/or after `find_brca` has run, but you can never know exactly what data `find_brca` used (without doing some serious low-level system probing with DTrace/ptrace, etc).

The root of the problem is that file paths do not have a 1:1 relationship with actual data. Only in a filesystem where files can only be requested by their checksum - and as soon as the data is modified its checksum is modified - can we ensure that when we feed `find_brca` the genome's file path `4fded1464736e77865df232cbcb4cd19`, we are actually reading the correct genome.

Are there any filesystems that work like this? If I wanted to create such a filesystem because none currently exists, how would you recommend I go about doing it?

Comment: I have trouble understanding tis question. So, the issue is that somebody "bad" might modify the file?

Comment: I kept it a little vague because there are many scenarios in which the file path doesn't point to the data you think it does. Corruption. Accidental/Deliberate switch of the file with another, either as a race-condition before execution or during the 4 hour runtime. Older versions used from backups/etc. Because at the end of the day when you give a program a filepath to analyse, you are making no guarantees about the data at the end of that path. In a filesystem where you can only request files based on their checksum and not by some arbitrary name, none of these issues exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my doubts about the stability, but hashfs looks exactly like what you want: http://hashfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> HashFS is a content-addressable file management system. What does that mean? Simply, that HashFS manages a directory where files are saved based on the  file’s hash. Typical use cases for this kind of system are ones where: Files are written once and never change (e.g. image storage). It’s desirable to have no duplicate files (e.g. user uploads). File metadata is stored elsewhere (e.g. in a database).

Note: Not to be confused with the hashfs, a student of mine did a couple of years ago: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1849837

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the question is a little vague, however, there are several answers which can be given to parts of your questions.

First of all, not all filesystems lack path/data correspondence. On many (if not most) filesystems, the file is identified only by its path, not by any IDs.

Next, if you want to guarantee that the data is not changed while the application handles them, then the approach depends on the filesystem being used and the way this application works with the file (if it keeps it opened or opens and closes the file as needed).

Finally, if you are concerned by the attacker altering the data on the filesystem in some way while the file data are used, then you probably have a bigger problem, than just the file paths, and that problem should be addressed beforehand.

On a side note, you can implement a virtual file system (FUSE on Linux, our CBFS on Windows), which will feed your application with data taken from elsewhere, be it memory, a database or a cloud. This approach answers your question as well.

Update: if you want to get rid of file paths at all and have the data addressed by hash, then probably a NoSQL database, where the hash is the key, would be your best bet.

Comment: You answers seem to address more the question "how do I get everything good about a filesystem without file paths, but still keep file paths?" I don't want or need file paths at all. A single "directory", with billions of files indexed by their SHA-1 sum, would do just fine - particularly if it was a copy-on-write system such that reading a file based on its hash guarantees the data you get back is the data you think it is, even if it's "modified" during the read. But unfortunately i've struggled to find anything like this. Perhaps a virtual file system is my best bet :) Thank you Eugene!

Comment: @J.J I've added the update to my answer. Go for NoSQL and use the hash as a key.

Comment: I love it - it perhaps a database won't work like a traditional filesystem (I was hoping to 'fool' programs that except file paths to accept hashes instead), but it certainly offers a bit more flexibility with transactional support, etc.

Comment: @J.J to fool the applications combine the database and the FUSE / CBFS approach with a virtual filesystem. You would then get the best of both worlds (DB and filesystem).